# JsonReaderException when parsing List<Class> in Nancy

Tags: c#, json.net, nancy

I am building a P2P Network with [nancy](/questions/tagged/nancy).
So far everything has gone fine. Now i am building my fingertables and want to parse them on using to other clients. But I get the following error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value
```

My Request:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"http://localhost:{port}/Successor/{id}");
    var chord = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ChordNode>();
    return chord;
}
```

which just returns:

```
Get["Successor/{id}", true] = async (x, ct) =>
{
    return _chordNode;
};
```

My class ChordNode worked fine until i added FingerTable list. It looks like the following:

```
public class ChordNode
{

    public NodeInfo Info { get; set; }

    public NodeInfo Successor { get; set; }
    public NodeInfo Predecessor { get; set; }
    public List<ChordNode> FingerTable { get; set; }

    ..... and other stuff thats not important.
```

If i make FingerTable private, it works again, but then i don't get my `FingerTable` returned to the other clients.

Still pretty new to asking questions on StackOverflow. So any feedback would be nice :)

Comment: can you paste a sample json response string? also, try getting the response in a string, and try doing a JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChordNode>(jsonStringValue);

Comment: Please post the json, otherwise nobody can tell why your json is not valid.

Comment: I don't have the json. Nancy handles everything behind the scene.

Comment: I'll try to add json to a string when I come home again.

Comment: Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the complete message, traceback and inner exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. 
After i removed all my ASYNC i got a better message telling me i used this part wrong.

```
Get["Successor/{id}", true] = async (x, ct) =>
```

i used my parameter x.id as a int in a method call and it gave me no feedback whatsoever. So after parsing this to a int it solved everything thing.

Thanks for all the nice feedback.